# Sql Query for unique record based on largest number

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a gridview that is currently displaying as you see in the top picture. I want it to display only the record that has the **Largest Time** as you see in picture two. For example, for Q1 largest time is 15 min, so only display Q1 15min, etc. This is dynamic so letters and numbers may change. Does anybody know a good sql server query for this?

UPDATED

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Will this work for you?

```
Select distinct Number, MAX(Time) from MyTable group by Number
```

---

after comments:

```
create table #example(number varchar(50), id int, [time] nvarchar(50), descr nvarchar(50))
insert into #example (number, id, [time], descr) values ('Q1', 1, '10 Min', 'Shoe')
insert into #example (number, id, [time], descr) values ('Q1', 1, '15 Min', 'Car')
insert into #example (number, id, [time], descr) values  ('Q1', 1, '6 Min', 'Shirt')
insert into #example (number, id, [time], descr) values  ('L2', 1, '10 Min', 'Shoe')
insert into #example (number, id, [time], descr) values  ('P3', 2, ' 8 Min', 'Garage')
insert into #example (number, id, [time], descr) values  ('P3', 2, ' 3 Min', 'Plant')
insert into #example (number, id, [time], descr) values  ('P3', 2, '20 Min', 'Tree')

SELECT t1.*
FROM #example AS t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN #example AS t2
    ON (t1.number = t2.number AND t1.[time] < t2.[time])
WHERE t2.number IS NULL;
--In other words: fetch the row from t1 where no other row exists with the same Number and a greater Time.
```

Comment: @Damith - bad habit on my part

Comment: @DanPichelman I updated my answer and it doesnt work with other columns involved. Any recommendations? Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for, but check it out:

```
create table #test (name varchar(10), number int)
insert into #test values ('a', 1)
insert into #test values ('a', 2)
insert into #test values ('a', 3)
insert into #test values ('b', 1)
insert into #test values ('b', 2)
insert into #test values ('b', 4)

select name, max(number) from #test group by name
```

Result:

```
name    (No column name)
a   3
b   4
```